# "Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success" and dependency errors, bad interpreter etc

Tags: apt, package-management

I keep trying to update with `sudo apt-get update` but run into errors after it runs and gets the update then spots and errors

- Files not found
- Problem executing script

and so on

[image: terminal with APT errors]

---

This is the output of the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall command-not-found`

[image: dependency errors]

This is after redoing my `sudo apt update`

[image: original error]

I tried to  do the repositories, based on the link all seems to have failed...

[image: python3 no such file or directory]

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text (they are harder to read, plus we can't copy/paste from them in order to help you), but edit your question and put the question there.  We can help you format if necessary (in questions & answers).

Comment: do not answer Your own question, just update your question. And If You know your answer ,then answer your own question and accept the same

Comment: Please launch `gnome-terminal` and copy textual output from `which python3` and `which python` commands to the question.